# In a JavaScript method signature what is meant by a return type of `typeof blahBlahBlah`?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, methods, return-type, typescript

I've seen an API list methods with both of the following signatures:

```
methodA(...) :        ReturnType

methodB(...) : typeof ReturnType
```

I understand the first but not the second.

My question comes from reading through the API for Angular2 where I encounter both of the above. For example, `class TestBed` lists two methods, [`initTestEnvironment`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/TestBed-class.html#!#initTestEnvironment-anchor) and [`configureTestingModule`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/TestBed-class.html#!#configureTestingModule-anchor), as:

```
initTestEnvironment(ngModule: Type<any>, platform: PlatformRef) : TestBed

configureTestingModule(moduleDef: TestModuleMetadata) : typeof TestBed
```

My understanding is that the first line means that when you call this method the return value will be an object of type `TestBed`. That makes sense to me.

However, I don't understand the type of the return value in the second line. Is the return value of this method an object of type `typeof TestBed`? The JS operator `typeof` returns a string, so how can you have an object of type `"Anything"` instead of `Anything`, i.e. a string versus a class/interface/etc.?

I am primarily interested in an explanation of this method signature syntax. However I would also very much appreciate a link to an (official?) online source describing this shorthand/syntax.

By the way, I presume that the syntax of this method signature is specific to TypeScript, but please correct me if I'm wrong about that.

*(I have attempted googling this question several ways, including keeping an eye out for StackExchange discussions, and have come up empty-handed. There is a question on StackOverflow that asks ["What is the return type of typeof?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3265676/5218951) which is completely unrelated. Other searches quickly disintegrate into Google separating `"typeof"` into `"type of"` which is also completely unhelpful.)*

Comment: Do you know what `TestBed` is?  Is it a variable/object or interface/class/enum?

Comment: @ErikEidt, `TestBed` is a type.

Comment: Have a read of https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html. Specifically the bit from "Next, we then use the class directly. Here we create a new variable called greeterMaker..." Hopefully it'll make more sense to you than it does to me! :)

Comment: is it not typescript rather than javascript? https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/05/31/type-queries-and-typeof-in-typescript

Comment: fyi, the construct `typeof variable` is also supported in TypeScript, so you can match the type of an object declared by fields instead of by interface.

Comment: @Ewan, the link you provided was very helpful. It corrects an important incorrect assumption I was making. For readers who don't click that link, it begins by stating: "TypeScript uses the typeof keyword for capturing anonymous types. Despite the same name, it is very different from JavaScript's typeof operator...." It seems counter-intuitive and confusing to me why TypeScript would seemingly misappropriate a keyword that already has a defined and different (even if related) meaning/usage in vanilla JavaScript, but at least I know now about the two distinct usages.

Comment: @DavidArno, it is true that `TestBed` is a type. However, the answer to @ErikEidt's question is that `TestBed` is a class.

Comment: @AndrewWillems: TypeScript is essentially C# in Javascript clothing (with some notable differences), and `typeof` is a keyword in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method signature returning `typeof` returns the constructor of the specified type, so that you can `new` it.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what the 2 different types actually represent. Let's say that I have `methodA(): MyClass` and `methodB(): typeof MyClass`. Is the following correct?: (1) the type of methodA includes the instance properties and instance methods of MyClass while (2) the type of methodB includes the constructor function as well as the static properties and static methods of MyClass.

Comment: That makes sense to me.  I wish I could advise you further... my answer was simply my boss's response when I asked him your question.

Comment: have you got a link to the documentation?

Comment: @Ewan, the best official documentation I've found so far is from @DavidArno's comment to my question, i.e. [the TypeScript documentation for Classes](http://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html). As David writes, the section on `typeof` is '...[s]pecifically the bit from "Next, we then use the class directly..."', near the bottom. I had read it before, but the `typeof` discussion had slipped past me. The section on `typeof` isn't long, so the comments/answers here definitely helped. (The link you provided in a comment to my question was also helpful...thx.)